# mysql display all rows from table that where added

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `FOLDERS`,everytime a folder is added through a php page it gets inserted into FOLDERS.
each folder has these fields: `id,userid,foldername`

I simplified the table to make my question easier to grasp.

ID UID FOLDERNAME

1  - 1    -   Books

2 -  1    -   Receipts

3  - NULL   - Books

4 -  NULL  -  Receipts

5 -  NULL  -  Home

6 - 2 - Receipts

I would like to know how to get the fifth row as a result.
The condition would be: The fact that row 5 doesnt have any UID (its empty) and is doesn't exist with a uid. When I use:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM folders WHERE  userid=''";
```

this returns ALL the rows with an empty userid. I only want 5 as a result because UID=1 already has his folder Receipts and Books set.
any suggestions would help I ve been struggling with this for a couple of hours now. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine a condition `userid IS NULL` for null userid rows with a `NOT IN()` subquery which returns all the distinct folder names which do have a `userid` in other rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM hpoptions
WHERE 
  userid IS NULL 
  AND foldername NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT foldername FROM hpoptions WHERE userid IS NOT NULL
  )
```